# Layout design using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have recently started using bootstrap framework to design webpages. In one of the webpages my intention was to show Home and Log out menu options at the right most side on the header. This looks fine when I check it in browser but I see that the menus (Home and Logout) disappear when the width of the browser is reduced.

Any body have any idea as to how this is happening.
This is the code I am using.

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container-fluid">  
      <div class="row"  style="background-color: #00509F; color: #FFFFFF">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-4">
          <h1>Page Title</h1>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>     
        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right">
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">            
              <li><a href="UserLogin.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="UserLogin.aspx" style="color: #FFFFFF">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-left: 5px">
          <asp:Menu ID="mnuMainMenu" runat="server" cssclass="menu" >
            <Items>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu Item1" Value="Menu Item1"     NavigateUrl="~/Page1.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu Item2" Value="Menu Item2" NavigateUrl="~/Page2.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu Item3" Value="Menu Item3" NavigateUrl="~/Page3.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu Item4" Value="Menu Item4" NavigateUrl="~/Page4.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu Item5" Value="Menu Item5" NavigateUrl="~/Page5.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu Item6" Value="Menu Item6" NavigateUrl="~/Page6.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu Item7" Value="Menu Item7" NavigateUrl="~/Page7.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
          </asp:Menu>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 " >      
          This is the place for Main content        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>     
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please RTFM, that's an explicit feature: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: This indentation looks like a step of Tour de France...

Comment: @zessx sheesh! You're goddamn right it does :D

Answer (score 0):

As @deceze said in the comments, it's an explicit feature.

To remove it, simple change;

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

To

```
<div class="navbar">
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zLDQv/

- Resize the output pane for full effect
- Paste your code in there, press run, and resize the output pane for full effect of them disappearing

*At least this works on the configuration of that fiddle.*